# Kivy: Events with Nested Layouts

Tags: events, kivy, event-handling, event-bubbling, event-propagation

I'm new to kivy and I don't understand how to handle event propagation.

A minimal example of what I'm trying to do:

```
# app.kv
ListItem:
    SomeIcon:
```

```
class ListItem(MDBoxLayout):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print('clicked on list item!')
            #return True # uncomment to stop propagation
        return super(ListItem, self).on_touch_down(touch)


class SomeIcon(MDIcon):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print('clicked on some icon!')
            return True
        return super(SomeIcon, self).on_touch_down(touch)
```

When I click on `SomeIcon` the event on `ListItem` is triggered first and then `SomeIcon`.

How can I prevent this and separate the events?

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: What do you mean by "*separate the events*"? Do you want the two print statements in the opposite order?

Comment: What is your understanding of the term "*event propagation*"? How do you expect events to work?

Comment: @Bergi I want to trigger the events isolated from each other.

Comment: @Bergi `SomeIcon` should not trigger the event on `ListItem`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `SomeIcon` should not trigger the event on `ListItem`

I think you're mistaken on how events work in Kivy. The library does not implement event propagation by itself and then dispatches `on_touch_*` events on every involved widget, like e.g. the DOM does it on the web. There is no built-in collision detection, Kivy won't know which widgets were touched and which were not, every widget needs to figure that out on its own.

I would argue that [the documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#widget-event-bubbling) "*events bubble up from the first child upwards through the other children. If a widget has children, the event is passed through its children before being passed on to the widget after it.*" is wrong or at least misleading.

What's actually happening is that the [main loop](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/events.html#main-loop) dispatches every input event at the root widget of the application, calling the respective `on_touch_*` method. This method is then responsible for propagating the event to the children widgets, and with a depth-first tree traversal it can form both [event capturing and event bubbling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616694/1048572). This recursion is happening in the [default `on_touch_*` method implementations](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/244635274821715b80abb0ea78e7751331986ca5/kivy/uix/widget.py#L569-L612) of the `Widget` class, which you're also doing by calling `super().on_touch_down(touch)`.

Depending on where in the method the recursive calls are happening, one can either handle events in the capturing phase or handle them in the bubbling phase. To do that latter, one has to *first* propagate the event to the children widgets and see whether one of them handled it, and only when none of them did, act on the event oneself. This is, in fact, what most method implementations do, see for example the [`on_touch_down` implementation of buttons](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/bb5a85724229a79a54b9e2cd2748ca979867e0d5/kivy/uix/behaviors/button.py#L137-L152) or [the recommended way to override the method](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/events.html), and is what you could do as well to get the desired behaviour:

```
class ListItem(MDBoxLayout):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if super(ListItem, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print('clicked on list item but not on the icon inside!')
            return True

class SomeIcon(MDIcon):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if super(SomeIcon, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print('clicked on some icon!')
            return True
```

However, for your example case you should [use a behaviour mixin](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.html), in particular the [`ButtonBehaviour`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.button.html):

```
class ListItem(MDBoxLayout, ButtonBehaviour):
    def on_press(self):
        print('clicked on list item but not on the icon inside!')

class SomeIcon(MDIcon, ButtonBehaviour):
    def on_press(self):
        print('clicked on some icon!')
```